# pass last few characters of string to new variable

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to help a friend with a php form that works fine and one of the variables is 'tourny' (it is the variable for which tournament they wish to play in and the last few characters of each option are the price, ie Midwestern Ontario District Junior Golf - $90.00.

I'm trying to be able to copy those last few characters to a new variable called $tcost. I've tried the command:

```
$tcost = substr(tourny, -6);
```

as well as:

```
$tcost = substr($_POST[tourny], -6);
```

to assign $tcost the last 6 characters of tourny - I'm not sure if it works or not because when I try to pass it to the emailer with the rest of the data where every variable is in `[]`, I've got:

Your cost for the tournament is: `[$tcost]`

But when I submit the form, all it sends by email is exactly that - no value for `$tcost`

I'm not sure if my error is in the substr command or in how I'm trying to pass it to the mailer.

I've also tried using a If/Then routine to assign a cost based on which tourny is selected and that doesn't work either.

If anyone has a way that it'll work, please let me know. I'm passable in html but php has me a bit confused.

Comment: Can you please confirm if your string has a trailing full stop or not? `Midwestern Ontario District Junior Golf - $90.00.` as `$90.00` is six characters but `$90.00.` is seven

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion This is a good scenario for a regular expression.

This matches the numeric value that appears after the dollar sign and before the end of the string

```
// (\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$

$string = 'Midwestern Ontario District Junior Golf - $90.00';
if( preg_match( '/\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/', $string, $matches ) )
{
  $cost = $matches[1];
  var_dump( $cost ); // string(5) "90.00"
}
```